# Spring Boot multi (maven) module project can't find its Repository -- how to fix this?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

As my first step in mastering Java 9 modules, I'm *first* creating a Java program that resides in nested directories, all joined by a root-level Maven pom.xml.  That is, Java modules aren't yet involved.

The source for my program is a Spring Boot program that already works.  I have divided that program into a controller (access Maven module) and data access (persistence Maven module).
My tutor for this task has been this Spring site:  https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/  .

I'm running this thru Visual Source Code, with Java 11 in my JAVA_HOME.  The Spring Boot program starts, then yields this sort of error:

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.logicaltiger.persistence.service.LocationService required a bean of type 'com.logicaltiger.persistence.repository.LocationRepository' that could not be found.
```

The program worked *before* I sliced / diced it, so my problem is with Spring configuration.

**My request?**  Can my configuration be fixed so that Spring Boot finds all of its parts?

The AccessApplication has this:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.logicaltiger")
@ComponentScan("com.logicaltiger")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class AccessApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AccessApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

LocationService has this:

```
@Service
[snip]

private final LocationRepository locationRepository;

public LocationService(LocationRepository locationRepository) {
    this.locationRepository = locationRepository;
}
```

LocationRepository has this:

```
@Repository
public interface LocationRepository extends CrudRepository<Location, Long> {
```

This is my directory structure, ignoring .mvn, etc.

```
district-updater-modules
    access
        src
            main
                java
                    com
                        logicaltiger
                            access
                                controller
                                    (various controller files, with @Controller annotation)
                                util
                                     Utilities.java
                                AccessApplication.java
                resources
                    static
                    templates
                    application.properties
        pom.xml
    persistence
            main
                java
                    com
                        logicaltiger
                            persistence
                                model
                                    (various model files)
                                repository
                                    LocationRepository.java
                                service
                                    LocationService.java
                                util
                                     Utilities.java
                                AccessApplication.java
                resources
        pom.xml
    pom.xml
```

The root pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" [snip] >
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.logicaltiger</groupId>
    <artifactId>district-updater-modules</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>district-updater-modules</name>
    <description>Wrapper for the modules of DistrictUpdater -- Java modules</description>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>access</module>
        <module>persistence</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

The access pom.xml (some dependencies omitted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" [snip] >
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.logicaltiger.access</groupId>
    <artifactId>access</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>district-updater-modules-access</name>
    <description>DistrictUpdater web API access module</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.logicaltiger</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The persistence pom.xml (some dependencies omitted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" [snip] >
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.logicaltiger</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>district-updater-modules-persistence</name>
    <description>DistrictUpdater persistence module</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Thanks,

Jerome.

Comment: Be careful about throwing instructions you don't really understand at the program in hopes of solving the problem. `@SpringBootApplication` already implies `@ComponentScan` and `@EnableAutoConfiguration`. You also don't need `@Repository` on a Spring Data repository. Finally, I note that you seem to have multiple copies of the `Application` class, which could be a problem.

Comment: Per suggestion, I removed those highlighted annotations, with no net effect.  I don't see where I have multiple Application classes.  Are you confusing SpringBootApplication (annotation) with SpringApplication (which starts my AccessApplication)?

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of surfing and experimenting, I finally found the solution [here](https://www.netsurfingzone.com/jpa/consider-defining-a-bean-of-type-in-your-configuration/).

In addition to `@ComponentScan("com.logicaltiger")` you also need

- `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.logicaltiger")` in order to find all repositories,
- and also `@EntityScan("com.logicaltiger.*")` in order to find all entities.

Hence:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.logicaltiger")
@ComponentScan("com.logicaltiger")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.logicaltiger")
@EntityScan("com.logicaltiger.*")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class AccessApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AccessApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```